# Why does my PHP script take so much time?

Tags: php, timeout, counter

I have a user table with currently a little over 6000 users.
All those users have a score, and I want to show that on a page, or ideally store in a view to show it later.

If I run my script for all 6000 users, it doesn't even finish.
If I run it for 200 users, the script takes about 2 minutes to run, and I don't understand why it is taking this long.

This is my script:

```
//Create $i: the position counter
$i = 0;
//Create $j: ex aequo counter
$j = 1;

//Take all users from the db with their id and their score
//Currently limited to 100 because it went so slow
$sql = 'SELECT `id`, `score` FROM `gebruikers` ORDER BY `score` DESC LIMIT 100';
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //If the current score is the same as the previous one (which has already been saved in $scoreboard[$i])...
    if($scoreboard[$i]["Finds"] == $row['score']) {
        // Then count how many in $j
        $j++;
        //Don't add up $i here, because we want to show ex aequo
    } else {
        //If not (so if the current score is different than the previous one), then add up the number of users that had the previous number to the position counter
        $i = $i + $j;
        //And set the ex aequo counter (back) to 1
        $j = 1;
    }
$scoreboard[$i]["Finds"] = $row['score'];
$scoreboard[$i]["IDs"][] = $row['id'];
}
```

The Result should be something like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Finds] => 294
            [IDs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2087
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Finds] => 289
            [IDs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 227
                    [1] => 3934
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Finds] => 284
            [IDs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 192
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Finds] => 279
            [IDs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4237
                    [1] => 4122
                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [Finds] => 278
            [IDs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1999
                )

        )
     etc...

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the while loop code with score as key. This will optimize the code.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $i = $row['score'];
    $scoreboard[$i]["Finds"] = $row['score'];
    $scoreboard[$i]["IDs"][] = $row['id'];
}
```

If you want the keys in 0,1,2 format, you can apply array_values to the scoreboard variable